# vue js, перечеркнутая линия изчезает после нажатия на кнопку "ДОБАВИТЬ"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

если нажать на чекбокс, то текст зачеркнется - но появляется ошибка : Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "complited"

и еще после нажатия на кнопку "добавить" зачеркнутые тексты вдруг превращаются в обычный текст(не зачеркнутый)

````
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>планировщик задач</title>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
   </head>
   <style>
       .todo-list-example{
           padding: 20px
       }
       
       .crossed{
       text-decoration: line-through;
       }
   </style>
   
   <body>
   <div id="todo-list-example">
     <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo">
       <label for="new-todo">Добавить задачу</label>
       <input
         v-model="newtodotext"
         id="new-todo"
         placeholder="Например, покормить кота"
         
       >
       <button>Добавить</button>
     </form>
     <ul>
       <li
         
         is="todo-item" 
         v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
         v-bind:key="todo.id"
         v-bind:title="todo.title"
         v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)"
       ></li><!-- is="todo-item" всеравно что использовать todo-item, но поволяет обходить проблемы парсинга -->
       {{newtodotext}}  
     </ul>
   </div>
   
   
   

   <script>
       Vue.component('todo-item', {
     template: `
       <li v-bind:class="{crossed: complited}">
           <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="complited = !complited" >
         {{ title }}
         <button v-on:click="$emit('remove')">Удалить</button>
       </li>
     `,
     props: ['title','complited']
   })
   new Vue({
     el: '#todo-list-example',
     data: {
       newtodotext: '',
       todos: [
         {
           id: 1,
           title: 'Помыть посуду',
           complited: false
   
         },
         {
           id: 2,
           title: 'Вынести мусор',
           complited:false
         },
         {
           id: 3,
           title: 'Подстричь газон',
           complited:false
         }
       ],
       nextTodoId: 4
     },
     methods: {
       addNewTodo: function () {
         this.todos.push({
           id: this.nextTodoId++,
           title: this.newtodotext,
           complited: false
           
         })
         this.newtodotext = ''
       }
     }
   })
   
   ```
   
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь изменить состояние Props'а, ошибка об этом и намекает. Нужно протягивать ивент до родительского компонента чтобы все заработало.

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    template: `
        <li :class="{ crossed: status }">
            <input type="checkbox" @change="toggleStatus">
            {{ title }}
            <button @click="remove">Удалить</button>
        </li>
    `,
    props: ['title', 'status'],
    methods: {
        toggleStatus() {
            this.$emit('toggle-status');
        },
        remove() {
            this.$emit('remove');
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#todo-list-example',
    data: {
        title: '',
        todos: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Помыть посуду',
                status: false

            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Вынести мусор',
                status: false
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Подстричь газон',
                status: false
            }
        ],
        lastInsertId: 3
    },
    methods: {
        addNewTodo: function() {
            this.todos.push({
                id: ++this.lastInsertId,
                title: this.title,
                status: false
            });
            this.title = '';
        },
        removeTodo(index) {
            this.todos.splice(index, 1);
        },
        toggleStatus(index) {
            this.todos[index].status = !this.todos[index].status;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.todo-list-example {
    padding: 20px
}

.crossed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="todo-list-example">
    <form @submit.prevent="addNewTodo">
        <label for="new-todo">Добавить задачу</label>
        <input v-model="title" id="new-todo" placeholder="Например, покормить кота">
        <button>Добавить</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
        <todo-item
            v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
            :key="todo.id"
            :title="todo.title"
            :status="todo.status"
            @toggle-status="toggleStatus(index)"
            @remove="removeTodo(index)"
        >
        </todo-item>
        {{ title }}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Вариант с помощью [`VUEX`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html)

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todos: [
            { name: "Learn JavaScript", status: false },
            { name: "Learn Vue", status: false },
            { name: "Play around in JSFiddle", status: true },
            { name: "Build something awesome", status: true }
        ],
        lastInsertId: 5
    },
    actions: {
        add: ({ commit }, todo) => commit('add', todo),
        toggle:({ commit }, index) => commit('toggle', index),
        removeByIndex: ({ commit }, index) => commit('removeByIndex', index),
        removeAll: ({ commit }, index) => commit('removeAll', index)
    },
    mutations: {
        add(state, todo) {
            state.todos.push({
                id: state.lastInsertId++,
                name: todo['name'] || '',
                status: todo['status'] || false
            });
        },
        toggle(state, index) {
            state.todos[index].status = !state.todos[index].status;
        },
        removeByIndex(state, index) {
            state.todos.splice(index, 1);
        },
        removeAll(state) {
            state.todos = [];
        }
    },
    getters: {
        todos: ({ todos }) => todos,
        todosCompleted: ({ todos }) => todos.filter(todo => todo.status).length
    }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    data: {
        name: ''
    },
    computed: {
        todos() {
            return this.$store.getters['todos'];
        },
        todosCompleted() {
            return this.$store.getters['todosCompleted'];
        }
    },
    methods: {
        remove(index) {
            this.$store.dispatch('removeByIndex', index);
        },
        toggle(index) {
            this.$store.dispatch('toggle', index);
        },
        add() {
            this.$store.dispatch('add', { name: this.name });
            this.name = '';
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #20262e;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
    margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.5.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Задачник:</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="add">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Название задачи" v-model="name">
        <button>Добавить</button>
    </form>
    <p>Всего задач: {{ todos.length }}</p>
    <p>Количество выполненных: {{ todosCompleted }}</p>
    <br>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" @change="toggle(index)" :checked="todo.status">
                <del v-if="todo.status">
                    {{ todo.name }}
                </del>
                <span v-else>
                    {{ todo.name }}
                </span>
                <button @click="remove(index)">x</button>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: а можешь обьяснить, в чем различия между vue и vuex, какой лучше? интересней? и где ты научился такому мастерству?

Comment: @Aizel это не мастерство, просто применял данные модули и практиковался. Vuex - обособленное но тесно связанное хранилище со `Vue`. Предоставляет возможность независимо от вложенности компонентов получать/изменять данные. Если у вас будет большой вложенности проект и вам нужно будет изменить какую-то переменную относящуюся к `Todo` (к примеру), то вы с легкостью можете воспользоваться методом и изменить, не проводя скатерть ивентов до родительского компонента где находился этот `todo list`. Я дал ответ с `Vuex` чисто для примера, в маленьком приложении он излишен, но если больше, то необходим.

Comment: в любом случае, твой опыт заметен, с первого ответа, я бы хотел узнать все же откуда ты брал знания по vue, и наработал практику

Comment: @Aizel видео уроки на youtube, документация, побольше практики и гуглежки тех или иных узконаправленных вопросов и запоминание полученной информации. Очень важно в этой сфере собирать информацию с разных источников и стараться выбирать более правильный, в ином случае есть шанс получить неверное представление от одного из объясняющих, поэтому - чем больше разных ораторов доносят одну и ту же информацию до вас, тем будет лучше связать ниточки и выбрать оптимальный вариант. Главное - применять и запоминать информацию, а дальше только копить и копить опыт.

Comment: Я лично много видео смотрел от [DKA-DEVELOP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Ac0jcqJIg), [Web Developer Blog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMYO487lpxg&list=PLVfMKQXDAhGWFP61AzOs_PowY7OAaFRHU) и [Владилен Минин](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCg8ss4xW9jASrqWGP30jXiw) . Отличные парни, попробуйте для себя открыть что-то новое и применить это на практике!